# MySQL ID column DATETIME + AUTO_INCREMENT (example: 13-04-2014-001, 13-04-2014-002 etc)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table which I want the ID column to be the auto-filled with the current date as well as an auto-increment number. This table is going to be for incident tickets, so for example, I want:
Ticket ID for ticket 1, submitted on 13/04/2014 to be 13-04-2014-001
Ticket ID for ticket 2, submitted on 13/04/2014 to be 13-04-2014-002
Ticket ID for ticket 3, submitted on 14/04/2014 to be 14-04-2014-001
Ticket ID for ticket 4, submitted on 14/04/2014 to be 14-04-2014-002
etc.

Just trying to figure out what the definition for this table column would be, something along the lines of

```
ticketID DATE NOT NULL (+ INT AUTO_INCREMENT),
```

I'm a little bit lost here, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Auto-increment columns must be numeric so you can't do things this way. You could use a trigger to create a ticket number from date and an auto-increment column when you're inserting your record.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the reply. Could you give an example of this? I'm not exactly sure what you mean, plus I haven't worked much with triggers.

Comment: you could update the table... add a ticket_id column that concats the date and the id together possibly

Comment: I think I know what you're saying John - need to look into triggers to have this update run after every insert (I'd assume that's more logical than doing it manually after every insert). Thanks!

Comment: yea so when you do an insert into the table your trigger would update with a new column that concats the date and id together to get the desired result. here is a link for trigger syntax with inserts ---- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html ----. hope its helpful!

Comment: Thanks to both of you - it turns out Mike is right, no updating the table that's just been inserted into. I was hoping that a second query wasn't necessary, but it looks like the only way to get done what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: @CodeMonkey13 You can't use a trigger for this after all. You can modify values to be inserted in a record with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, but then don't have access to the autoincremented ID. You have access to it in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, but then the record is inserted and you can't change the values. You can't run an `UPDATE` query on the table that triggered the procedure. My best suggestion is a second query as part of a stored procedure, or as part of your application logic.